# Adding Custom Theme for the application

Tags: css, extjs4, sass, extjs4.1

I am experimenting on themes. For this i have downloaded and installed ruby.

I am clueless as in how to have a different `css` file to have my own theme for the application.

I think i have make changes to a file with an extension `.scss`. Can someone walk me through the steps to have my own theme for the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not you define partials for theme and put theme related stuff in variables. These partials whould'nt create any .css file. Here is example

Make 3 files home.scss, _homePartials.scss and _homeTheme.scss

_homePartials.scss

```
$textColor: #333;
```

_homeTheme.scss

```
.text { color:$textColor; }
```

home.scss

```
.text { width:100%; }
@import '../partials/homePartials';
@import '../partials/homeTheme';
```

take a look at http://blog.behance.net/dev/how-we-used-sass-to-build-17-websites-in-five-days

Comment: Thank you, can i have some reading material so i could read more about this ? and do i have to create a folder called `Partials` and place those files in that ?

Comment: yes you can create partials folder or what you like. As you define theme related stuff in a variable file called partail you can always have option to set different and thus have themes

Comment: How do i reference this files from the `index.html`

Comment: what do you mean? you will have .css file for instance home.css here simple link them in html file